# How to create divs with static size

Tags: css, html

I need some advices on how to create a website in a way that it will keep its size on every resolution.

I've tried in many ways but I never made it work, and it's hard to understand responsive web design because I can't find it in my language. I just want some brief advices, and simple explanations about how to keep resolutions of content divs on different resolutions in CSS/HTML

`Here's` what I've tried until now but it didn't work:

There are just the codes without images, its just a way to see what I did wrong and what I should do.

Comment: You know that notice that tells you not to post a jsFiddle if it's not accompanied by code? It's there for a reason.

Comment: well your css is a little bit off... do you have experience in web design? check this i cleared some code form your css http://jsfiddle.net/gW9vv/1/

Comment: panagiotis as i said i've learnd everything by myself.In my language the only web design articles are the basic ones.So i worked with what i had.

Comment: thank you for your work panagiotis....i know im such a headache,i dont know how to learn it....btw the edit you've made for #image1 it's not working .... i mean it stil change his size on a different resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this piece of code and play with it to get a basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx5Xn/1/

Furthermore I would advise you to check some online tutorials.

Check

```
http://www.w3schools.com/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design
```

Comment: well i've read a little bit of them but its worthless...it's kinda hard to understand them if i cant see some code and website examples...